# HackerRank Classification Timeout Problem

Tags: python

I just try to compile this code but I always face Timeout problem in hackerrank.
Traningdata.txt is data file in hackerrank.
This project about document classification.
Training data includes sentences and labels.
I tried to tokenize sentences and work with them.
In Conclusion,I Printed all y_head values but my code doesnt run as long as can be printed.

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

from sklearn import model_selection, preprocessing, naive_bayes
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
import nltk 
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nltk.download('stopwords')
ps=PorterStemmer()
documents=[]

data=pd.read_csv("trainingdata.txt",header=None)
T=data[0][0]
data.drop(data.index[0],inplace=True)
sentences=[]
labels=[]
for each in data.iloc[:,0]:
    each=each.split(" ",1)
    labels.append(each[0])
    sentences.append(each[1])
sentences=pd.DataFrame(sentences)
labels=pd.DataFrame(labels)
dataFrame=pd.concat([sentences,labels],axis=1)
dataFrame.columns=["Sentence","Label"]

for each in range(0,dataFrame.shape[0]):
    yorum=re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]",' ',dataFrame["Sentence"][each])
    yorum=yorum.lower()
    yorum=nltk.word_tokenize(yorum)
    yorum=[ps.stem(kelime) for kelime in yorum if not kelime in set(stopwords.words("english"))]
    yorum=' '.join(yorum)
    documents.append(yorum)

cv=CountVectorizer(max_features=2000)
x=cv.fit_transform(sentences).toarray()
y=dataFrame["Label"].values

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
nb=GaussianNB()
nb.fit(x,y)
y_head=nb.predict(x)
for each in y_head:
    print(each)
```